# Clion warning "The address of the local variable may escape the function"

Tags: c++, clion

I just have started learning C++ and am trying to work with binary tree. I cannot find an answer if should I fix this warning "The address of the local variable may escape the function"? I have class `BinaryTree`. This class has two pointers `BinaryTree * left = nullptr;` and `BinaryTree * right = nullptr;` Also my class has method `void BinaryTree::randomTree(bool grow, bool actDepth, short maxDepth, short depth = 0)`

From very beginnig I make empty tree

```
BinaryTree tmpTree = BinaryTree(
                minDepth,
                mProbability,
                cProbability
        );
```

Then I want to grow this tree

```
        tmpTree.randomTree(
                (bool) Helper::fiftyFifty(),
                (bool) Helper::fiftyFifty(),
                Helper::getRandomNumber(minDepth, maxDepth + 1)
        );
```

And I have a warning in `randomTree` method

```
... some code ...
        BinaryTree lTmpTree = BinaryTree(
                this->minDepth,
                this->mProbability,
                this->cProbability
        );
        this->left = &lTmpTree;  // <---- I have warning there

        this->left->randomTree(grow, actDepth, maxDepth, depth + (short) add);
... some code ...
```

Tell me please if I should be worried about this warning?

Comment: Just do `this->left = nullptr;` before leaving the function.

Comment: @Eljay Thank for your answer. Could you explain me why? In this case my left tree won't grow

Comment: Because `lTmpTree` is a local variable, that is destructed at the end of the function.  That means `this->left` will be a dangling pointer, that refers to a smoldering crater where `lTmpTree` used to exist.

Comment: You should be worried about *all* warnings, and in particular those that you don't quite understand.

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you! Some answers I am finding in internet, if I cannot I ask here ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scope issue. You make a local variable, `lTmpTree`, which will get destroyed when you exit local scope.

You're taking a reference to that local variable, though

```
this->left = &lTmpTree;
```

which is dangerous because, as mentioned at the top, `lTmpTree` gets destroyed when you leave local scope. This means the bits for `lTmpTree` might still exist correctly in memory if they haven't been re-allocated for something else, but you can't count on it. This is why you get the warning.

Comment: I thought if I assigned the reference a value to another variable I won't lose a value. Thank you!

Comment: @Deadpool if you store the *value* you won't lose the value, but you're saving the *address* and the house at that address is getting bulldozed.

Comment: @Deadpool thanks, you too! Good luck with your project :D